# Weekly Loan payment/ Amortization Schedule Calculation logic in c#

Tags: c#, banking

I have completed Loan Amortization/ Loan Repayment calculation for monthly. Now i required for weekly calculation formula in c#.

Can any one please help me to answer this?

Here loan amount is 10000, Interest Rate is 10% and Terms 7 Months

This is my monthly calculation. but i need weekly calculation like this

```
loanAmount = 10000;
var periods = 7; //Months
var monthlyRate = (Convert.ToDouble(10) / 100) / 12;
var monthlyPayment = Math.Round(monthlyRate / (1 - Math.Pow((1 + monthlyRate), -(periods))) * loanAmount ,2);
```

Thanks in advance,
Mani

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly how you are calculating it, it should be as simple as switching out months for weeks. For example, instead of something like this:

```
monrthly payments = (balance * APR) / 12 months
```

Do this:

```
weekly payments = (balance * APR) / 52 weeks
```

Obviously you'll change it depending on what you're calculating and how you're calculating it. You've already done the hard part now you just have to change the time frame, does that make sense?

Comment: This is my calculation for monthly. But i need weekly calculation. var loanAmount = 10000;
var periods = 7; //Months
var monthlyRate = (Convert.ToDouble(10) / 100) / 12;
var monthlyPayment = Math.Round(monthlyRate / (1 - Math.Pow((1 + monthlyRate), -(periods))) * loanAmount ,2);

Comment: My monthly calculation based on the formula given here, https://emicalculator.net/ I need same like for a weekly calculation